# Rails 4.2.6 migration to 5.0.0 (belongs_to_required_by_default)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm upgrading my Rails 4.2.6 App to 5.0.0 (maybe, I'll be trying 5.1 or 5.2 if everything goes OK).

There's a new Active Record configuration default introduced in 5.0.0 that I'm seeing in my config/new_framework_default.rb:

```
# Require `belongs_to` associations by default. Previous versions had false.
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

So basically every `belongs_to` association will be validated for presence by default.

**My issue is:**

I would really like to have this configuration in `false`, because I'd prefer to validate the presence of the foreign key field. For instance:

```
class Discount < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'Customer', :foreign_key => :customer_id

    validates :customer_id, presence: true 

end
```

Also, I have +250 models in my App and +4000 `belongs_to` associations. So, this could take a while for me and could be a major breaking change for my App.

**Questions:**

- Is there anything wrong if I set the configuration to false? And keep it that way for an undefined period of time.
- Would that be broken in future Rails versions? > 5.0.0

Thanks!

Comment: IMO, you should be fine. That's why it's available as a configuration.

Comment: Thanks @jvillian, everything seems to be working OK. I opted for the Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false

Comment: They added the option so you can turn that off and return to the old behaviour, check the docs https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

Comment: Make sure you create a reminder to refactor this and add the optional: true on the belongs_to statements that don't need the validation. I forgot about it and had to deal with it once I went to 5.2 from 5.1